# 18.04: Remove Tilix and its configuration

Tags: 18.04

How can you get back to the default settings in [Tilix](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/tilix.1.html) ([home page](https://gnunn1.github.io/tilix-web/))?

I have been trying but I can't find the option.

I also tried reinstalling but it keeps inheriting my previous modified settings...

I have tried:

```
sudo dpkg -r tilix
sudo apt-get remove tilix
sudo apt-get purge tilix
sudo apt remove tilix
sudo apt purge tilix
```

My OS is Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS.

Tilix is very nice, the closest to iTerm but I don't know why it is so difficult to be cleansed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The configuration is stored in [dconf](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/dconf) under **com.gexperts.Tilix** and you can adjust parameters with [dconf-editor](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/dconf.1.html)

A tutorial on adding zsh and Powerline was also recommended, and it can be seen at https://linuxhint.com/install_zsh_shell_ubuntu_1804/

Comment: With this solution I managed to get back the default config and then clone that config to customize mine. Thanks!
Just a quick question... If I wanted the git info in my Tilix to be shown just like in the picture here, what should I do? https://camo.githubusercontent.com/3178e6b3193f24471bd60f48b6faba15e0536b71/68747470733a2f2f676e756e6e312e6769746875622e696f2f74696c69782d7765622f6173736574732f696d616765732f67616c6c6572792f74696c69782d73637265656e73686f742d312e706e67

Comment: For that, I must profess utter ignorance. However, it _may_ require Powerline https://github.com/powerline/powerline/blob/develop/README.rst , for in the FAQ of Tillix https://gnunn1.github.io/tilix-web/faq I read "Where is the option to get the cool colored prompts like in the screenshots? That comes from powerline and is not something Tilix provides."

Comment: Very nice info @K7AAY 
For the sake of completion I found this useful tutorial to make the whole change https://linuxhint.com/install_zsh_shell_ubuntu_1804/

Comment: So, you want zsh and Tillix and Powerline? Please, for the sake of those who follow, click https://askubuntu.com/posts/1216166/edit and mention you are using zsh .. I added your suggested tutorial to my answer to preserve it, because comments will eventually get filtered out

Comment: Well, I didn't have zsh initially, I just followed the tutorial to the end... And I found it interesting.